# Does having your GPU and CPU and case fans all running at max speed damage them?

Tags: cooling

I almost never need to have my fans at max speed, but I always like to have them at max speed to boost performance. Are there any negatives to having all your fans at max speed all the time?

Comment: If your over-clocked like a lot of gaming video cards are, it might be a good idea to have them work alot, however, like everything else, yes, they can wear faster. The best practice is to let the CPU's fan voltage regulator do the work, when your processor has a workload it will faster to cool. Just keep them clean with compress air or other device.  Here is a pretty good page https://lifehacker.com/control-your-computers-fan-speeds-for-better-performanc-5866009

Comment: Fans at max speed has nothing to do with boosting performance. This is supposed to happen automatically *when required*.

Answer (score 0):

> but I always like to have them at max speed to boost perforance

This is a bad idea for several reasons:

1. Some NVidia GPUs actually Decrease performance if the fans are at max speed. This is in firmware and you can't modify this behavior.
2. The fans' bearings will wear out in time.
3. Unless the GPU/CPU is overheating and self throttling, having the fans at any speed is completely unrelated to performance.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is incorrect.  You do not need to run your fans at max speed to boost performance.  When your CPU or GPU are working hard, the fans will *automatically* spin faster to cool them as needed.  You are not gaining any performance by having the fans spin faster when not needed.  All you are doing is making more audible fan noise.  Also, you are using more electricity, although small in the grand scheme.

Will this damage your fans?  *Technically*, yes.  In real world usage, no.  Fans are *designed* to spin fast for years.  A quality should be able to operate at full speed for longer than you will be using that computer.  That being said, a fan is a moving mechanical part.  They *will* eventually wear out.  A poorly made fan, will use cheaper plastics, bearings, spindles, etc.  However, even cheap fans will last *many* years- into decades.  Even if a fan does fail, they are cheap and replaceable.  In short, you do not need to worry about them.

Answer (score 0):

> I almost never need to have my fans at max speed, but I always like to have them at max speed to boost performance

Heat is produced when electronics work hard.  Electronics are also affected by heat surrounding them.

Some electronics automatically throttle when they get too hot.

Fans take away heat.

Fans can stop electronics from automatically throttling, but there's only a benefit if your electronics are working hard enough to need it.

If your electronics are idle (and ideally they'd go in a low power state in that case), you're only increasing wear and tear on the fan.